# Access FB graph API for public URL's share count past FB hit limit

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api

I was fetching FB like and shares for public pages like news sites.
I was showing top news on my blog form various news portals and their FB activity.These portals are independent sites and no issue while sharing this data.

http://www.wsj.com/articles/opera-software-to-sell-internet-browser-operations-to-chinese-consortium-1468831077

FB activity for this URL is 28.
As FB now has a limit of 4800 hits per day I am stuck with the limit.

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2016/06/16/page-level-rate-limits/

I tried to connect to FB team for their any subscription mode which can be used to increase this limit but none is achieved.
People use multiple servers to hit FB from different domain to bypass this but that looks not a valid approach.
I tried page access token, user access token, app access token everything.

Can anyone suggest me how i can achieve this. Any subscription model will work but directly form Facebook.

Thanks
Virendra Agarwal

Comment: you can´t circumvent the limits, and there is no way to increase them. using multiple server is definitely not allowed. limits are there for a reason, 4800 is a LOT and you should decrease the amount of api calls. THAT would be the proper solution.

Comment: Hi I am accessing it using batch request but for each URL in batch request a separate hit is counted. I saw some sites which show data from FB for any URL they sell it too. I need this form Facebook if they have something like this as other sites are already doing this.

Comment: of course. batch requests are only faster, they don´t circumvent limits. that would be weird. those other sites usually cache results. you should do that too. again, 4800 calls is way too much, you need to reduce the amount of calls. with that many calls, you are definitely doing it wrong.

Comment: @luschn cache is not the solution as i read terms in those sites you can hit for 100k URLs at one time and get there latest results . I tried with one for limited subscription to verify it and then i check the results at graph APIs it was same. So data was latest that where i get idea for subscription from FB if possible.

Comment: then those sites most likely use multiple servers and tokens, which is definitely not allowed. again, if you hit the limits, you are doing something you are not supposed to. limits are there for a reason.

Comment: @luschn got it thanks. I have already change my code to be in limit lets see if FB give more freedom in future.